# What is the meaning of the movie title "The Way Way Back"?

Tags: title, the-way-way-back

The subject of the movie is a dull boy who works in a water park and his mother's boyfriend is cheating her.

Why is the movie titled "The Way Way Back"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no official confirmation but the consensus is that the title refers to the "way back seat," the 1970s colloquial expression for the third, often-hidden seat located in the cargo section of a station wagon.

[image]

[FlickPhilospopher](http://www.flickfilosopher.com/2013/08/the-way-way-back-review-how-to-escape-from-your-family.html)

> What does the title mean? It’s a bit of a mystery… but it could refer to the penchant of 14-year-old Duncan (Liam James: 2012, Fred Claus) to escape to the way, way back of the old-fashioned station wagon, to the seat that faces backward out the rear of the car, to not have to cope with his family. (This scenario opens the film, and the film will return to it, poignantly, in the end.)

[**Hollywood Reporter**](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/review/way-way-back-sundance-review-414197)

> The title refers to the rear-facing back seat of a vintage station wagon

[**IMDB Trivia**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1727388/trivia) (so unconfirmed)

> The script was written in 2007 as "The Way Back", but the title was later changed to avoid confusion with the film The Way Back (2010). The title refers to the "way back seat," the 1970s colloquial expression for the third, often-hidden seat located in the cargo section of a station wagon.

Comment: Movie ends with "Pam climbs to the way, way back of the car where Duncan is sitting and they share a smile as Trent's protests are heard in the background." I just love this film and was in middle of giving similar answer but now not needed

Comment: I picked the line form Wikipedia description and also remember from my memory too.

Comment: Ok...I can't find that in the transcript so I'll hold off for now